# Failed to load resource: 500 error in Salesforce when using a jQuery in sidebar component

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, apex-code

As you all know that we cannot access custom labels (I might be wrong here) in sidebar component, like we do in vf pages({!$label.labelname}), I had to write a webService class in apex which will return the custom label and I use the sforce.apex.execute to access that class in jQuery script. Now, when the home page is loaded, the sidebar components load correctly and the below script executes without any problem. But when I enter some text in the textbox and search the text, myVfPage loads in a new tab with expected result, but again when I enter some text in the sidebar component and click on search I am not redirected to myVfPage. When I check the console in see 2 error which says:[image: javascriptError]. This is what the error messages read:

1:- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

2:-Uncaught {faultcode:'sf:INVALID_SESSION_ID', faultstring:'INVALID_SESSION_ID: Invalid Session ID found in SessionHeader: Illegal Session', }

Not sure what to do here kindly help

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/jQuery"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/connection"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resource/apexjs" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
var sid = getCookie('sid'); 
var server = "https://"+window.location.host+"/services/Soap/u/26.0";
alert(server);
sforce.connection.init(sid, server);
var custLabelSearchText = sforce.apex.execute("JqueryCustomLabelController","getCustomLabel", {});
j$(document).ready(function(){
   alert(getCookie('sid'));
   j$("#searchIt").bind('click', function(){
     if(j$("#userInput").val() == ''){
        alert(custLabelSearchText);
        custLabelSearchText ='';
    }else{
        window.open("/apex/myVfPage?searchText="+(j$("#userInput").val()), "_blank");
    }
});
});
</script>
<b>Search your Text here</b><br/>
<input id="userInput"  type="text"/><br/>
<input type="button" value="Search" id="searchIt"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try to insert session ID in the page header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var __sfdcSessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}';
</script>
```